# C++ smart pointer for a non-object type?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, shared-ptr, auto-ptr

I'm trying to use smart pointers such as auto_ptr, shared_ptr. However, I don't know how to use it in this situation.

```
CvMemStorage *storage = cvCreateMemStorage();
... use the pointer ...
cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage);
```

I'm not sure, but I think that the storage variable is just a malloc'ed memory, not a C++ class object. Is there a way to use the smart pointers for the storage variable?

Thank you.

Comment: There's no way we can tell you how the memory is allocated without seeing the source of `cvCreateMemStorage`. It might be `malloc`ed, it might be `new`ed, it might not be anything, maybe the function `cvCreateMemStorage` always returns `NULL`.

Comment: Are you sure that `cvReleaseMemStorage` takes a `CvMemStorage**` instead of a `CvMemStorage*` ? That seems odd.

Comment: Odd indeed, but [it does](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/dynamic_structures.html#releasememstorage).

Comment: @ereOn: yeah, it thakes a CvMemStorage**, I think it may set the pointer to NULL after release resources.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`shared_ptr` allows you do specify a custom deallocator. However, looking at the documentation `cvReleaseMemStorage()` doesn't have the right form (`void f(T*)`) and you need a wrapper:

```
void myCvReleaseMemStorage(CvMemStorage* p) {
   cvReleaseMemStorage(&p);
}

shared_ptr<CvMemStorage> sp(cvCreateMemStorage(), &myCvReleaseMemStorage);
```

Comment: Also note that this feature of `shared_ptr` is often underestimated. For an `auto_ptr` to work, the user needs to know how to release it, however with an `auto_ptr` you specify how to release at construction time, and then it's hidden away and the user never needs to worry about it. And of course the default is a classic `delete` call.

Answer (score 1):

The `shared_ptr` class allows for you to provide a custom delete function/functor, you could simply wrap the `cvReleaseMemStorage` function in a function and provide that for `shared_ptr` along with the pointer you want it to manage for you?